# webpack-dev-serverで自動コンパイル・画面更新できない

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack

この度フロントエンドに入門しようとしています。

### やりたいこと

webpack及びその周辺技術を用いて、
- js及びcssが保存時(ファイル変更時)にウォッチされ自動コンパイルされる
- 自動コンパイルされた際に、ブラウザ(localhost:8080 ??)が自動でリロードされる

### やったこと

以下のようにyarnとwebpackで環境構築をしました。

[image: ディレクトリ]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: [
      './javascript/index.js',
      './javascript/skrollr.min.js',
    ],
    output: {
      path: publicDir,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      contentBase: './',
      inline: true,
      hot: true,
    },
  },
  {
    entry: {
      style: './stylesheets/index.scss',
    },
    output: {
      path: publicDir,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.css',
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' }),
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!sass-loader' }),
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
    ],
  },
];
```

### 症状

`yarn run start`後、index.js及びindex.scssの変更・保存時にコンパイルのようなログが流れるものの、bundle.jsやbundle.cssは更新されていない(ブラウザで確認しても変化していない)。
また、ブラウザも自動でリロードされない。
ログ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ネットで色々調査して改変などしましたが、バージョンなどの差なのかうまく動作しません。どなたかご教授をお願いいたします。。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/105422

Answer (score 1):

自己解決:
index.htmlを`public/`に移動し、`contentBase: publicDir`とすることで`やりたいこと`が突然満たされました。理由は謎ですが・・・。